# How do I utilize the "using" statement correctly for my code

Tags: c#, object, idisposable, using

This is my code:

```
Bitmap bmp = ImageManipulator.GetMyImageModified(bmp);
Bitmap tempBMP = ImageManipulator.cropImage(bmp, rect);
tempBMP = ImageManipulator.CopyToBpp(tempBMP, 1);

string bmpFilename = String.Format("File{0}.png", indexNum);
tempBMP.Save(bmpFilename, ImageFormat.Png);
```

Now I've seen that for IDisposable objects is a best practice to use the using statement to dispose those object as soon as they are not needed anymore.
I want to follow this practise and so I need some help rewriting the above code:

```
using (Bitmap bmp = ImageManipulator.GetMyImageModified(bmp){

   Bitmap tempBMP = ImageManipulator.cropImage(bmp, rect); // bmp should be disposed after this line
   tempBMP = ImageManipulator.CopyToBpp(tempBMP, 1);

   string bmpFilename = String.Format("File{0}.png", indexNum);
   tempBMP.Save(bmpFilename, ImageFormat.Png); 
} // bmp is disposed here
```

This is my first attempt but it's not perfect cause the **bmp** Bitmap is non disposed as soon as not needed anymore though in this specific example shouldn't be mandatory to get it disposed so fast.

**tempBitmap** is more problematic because i cannot reassign the reference to a new Object inside the using statement that should surrond:

```
Bitmap tempBMP = ImageManipulator.cropImage(bmp, rect);
```

Indeed **tempBMP** reference becomes *readonly* after surrounding the above line with the *using* keyword.

Also tempBMP gets saved to a file and the Save operation should be asyncrhonous and then I don't know the effects of a dispose as soond as the:

```
tempBMP.Save(bmpFilename, ImageFormat.Png);
```

Get called.

If you can help me write better code, I'm all ears.

Comment: `Save()` is not asynchronous.

Comment: You have two different bitmaps in `tempBMP`, and you should dispose both of them. So you need to split it into two variables anyways.

Comment: @Slaks Thanks for having rectified the problem.

Comment: In general, at least with fungible resources like bitmaps, one shouldn't worry about calling Dispose on an IDisposable at the first possible moment.  What is important is that Dispose gets called in a foreseeable time frame.  It's usually better to nest using blocks and let later-created objects get disposed before earlier-created ones, than to create and destroy objects in more arbitrary sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using (var sourceBmp = ...)
using (var modifiedBmp = ImageManipulator.GetMyImageModified(sourceBmp))
using (var croppedBmp = ImageManipulator.cropImage(modifiedBmp, rect))
using (var finalBmp = ImageManipulator.CopyToBpp(croppedBmp, 1))
{
    string bmpFilename = String.Format("File{0}.png", indexNum);
    finalBmp.Save(bmpFilename, ImageFormat.Png); 
}
```

Comment: Yes this looks correct, and splitting the variables the way to go.

Is the "var" usage convenient, needed or a better practise in this case ?

Comment: @Relok, that's more of a personal preference. The usage of the `var` keyword has already been discussed on StackOverflow and I don't want to influence your decision. Personally I use it all the time because I am lazy.

Comment: Anyway for each bitmap the disposing happens just after the last using var finalBmp codeblock, right ?
So it's basically as what I've written in my question, with the difference that your code takes care of all the bitmaps instead of only "bmp", right ?

Comment: Little addon question related to your Answer: What if in my original code I had an if statement to check if the sourceBmp was null, how do I write the using blocks ?

I can bypass this making checks for null in every method of the code snippet, but still I would like to know how should I change my code if I don't choose this way.

Answer (score 1):

The *using* keyword is just a convenience.  Calling Dispose() explicitly is still quite possible.  Do so in a finally block.  Arbitrarily:

```
        Bitmap bmp = ImageManipulator.GetMyImageModified(bmp);
        var t = new Thread(() => {
            try {
                using (var croppedBmp = ImageManipulator.cropImage(bmp, rect))
                using (var copiedBmp = ImageManipulator.CopyToBpp(tempBMP, 1)) {
                    string bmpFilename = String.Format("File{0}.png", indexNum);
                    copiedBmp.Save(bmpFilename, ImageFormat.Png);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                ReportFailure(ex);
            }
            finally {
                bmp.Dispose();
            }
        });
        t.Start();
```

Comment: A question about your example using the lamda expression for the new Thread. The finally statement happens inside the new thread, from what I see in this way I can pass an arbitrary number of parameters to it, in your example the bmp Bitmap. But what happens if the bmp goes out of scope of the method called in main thread, while still the new thread has not yet completed ?

Comment: Nothing.  The *bmp* variable value gets captured by the lambda.  So does the *indexNum* variable value.

Comment: If an exception gets thrown while creating or starting the new thread, bmp will get leaked.  Also, as noted in Relok's answer, it looks like whatever bitmap was originally in bmp might get leaked regardless.

Comment: If creating a thread throws an exception then the game is pretty much over.  No point in trying to continue when so few system resources are left.

Comment: @supercat can you explain better your last statement and why a leak might happen "regardless".